# how do you read the state?(UseState)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, webhooks

** when I start the software for the first time the "items" state property is not valued. Not even setItems. If I try to reload a second time instead it is valued. How can I change the following code to make the status value also on first opening?**

[image]

How can I change the following code to make the status value also on first opening?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I don't think you will ever be able to have `items` populated on first load, because you populate it from the result of an async function, which you call on first load.  So you will always have to wait for that async function to finish before you have any `items`.

Comment: Remove the `setItems([])` from your `useEffect`. You've already initialized items to an empty array in the useState([]) call. There is definitely a period of time where the items will be empty and attempt to render (though it may be very short). That will be an empty div with your current code. Recommend adding a loading message or gif conditionally shown.